# Non existence of Prime models

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a countable language. Let $T$ be a complete $L$ theory. We know that if $T$ is small, then there is a prime model of the theory. But $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},+,\times,0,1)$ is not small but it has a prime model.

As far as I'm aware there is no necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of prime models. But I would like to see how to show certain theories do not have prime models. For example, how would you show that any  consistent extension of ZFC doesn't have a prime model? (I strongly suspect that is the case).

Edit 1: To clarify: I'm asking if there is a "standard" argument that you can try when you suspect a theory doesn't have a prime model.

Comment: What is a prime model? Is it something like a prime field?

Comment: @bof It is a model of $T$ that embeds elementarily into any model of $T$.

Comment: Doesn't ZFC have a model $M$ in which each element is definable? And isn't $M$ a prime model for the theory $\operatorname{Th}(M)$?

Comment: @bof No, there are theories without prime models. So $M$ isn't always a prime model for $Th(M)$. Also the concepts only make sense for complete theories, and ZFC is not. That's why the question is phrased the way it is (.....every completion of ZFC.....)

Comment: @bof I think your answer contributed a lot, I hope you'll undelete it! kav11, you misunderstood bof's comment: It doesn't say *every* $M$ is prime for $\text{Th}(M)$. Rather, *if* $M$ is a pointwise-definable model of ZFC, then $M$ is a prime model for $\text{Th}(M)$: $\text{Th}(M)$ is a complete extension of ZFC and $M$ is a model which realizes only isolated types. This is a nice observation, since it's the same reason $\mathbb{N}$ is an atomic model for true arithmetic: every element is definable (even given by a term, in the case of $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I see. I did misunderstand that. Even under the assumption on Con(ZFC) or something even stronger, does it follow that such a model exists? I didn't see how to prove/disprove the existence of such a model. I was initially thinking about the constructible sets but that uses parameters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *is* a simple necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a prime model: "isolated types are dense". If $T$ is a complete theory in a countable language, then

1. If $M\models T$, then $M$ is prime if and only if $M$ is countable and atomic (meaning that $M$ realizes only isolated types over the empty set).
2. $T$ has a countable atomic model if and only if isolated types are dense (meaning that for every formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$, there is an isolated type $p(\overline{x})$ in $S^n(\varnothing)$ such that $\varphi\in p$).

These facts should be proven in every model theory textbook - they're Theorems 4.2.8 and 4.2.10 in Marker, for example. The situation is more subtle if $L$ is uncountable (largely because it's harder to omit types), and I suspect there's not a satisfying general criterion for the existence of prime models in that context.

One more comment: To prove that $T$ does *not* have a prime model, you need to come up with a formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$ which is not contained in any isolated type. This means $[\varphi(\overline{x})]$ is a perfect set in the Stone space, so there must be continuum-many types containing $\varphi(\overline{x})$. This is why small theories have prime models.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea for the extensions of ZFC? I'm not sure how to come up with such a formula.

Comment: Given @bof s answer, things are probably very complicated. I took a look at the paper by Hamkins et al. It looks like you need to look at models of $ZFC+HOD\neq{V}$.

Comment: Also, that should be "I" not "you" but grammar is strange at times :)

Answer (score 3):

I address the part of your question which asks "how would you show that any consistent extension of ZFC doesn't have a prime model?" In fact (assuming of course that ZF is consistent), some consistent extensions of ZFC do have prime models.

Let $M$ be a model of ZFC in which each element is definable. (Such "pointwise definable" models of set theory were the subject of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified).) Then $T=\operatorname{Th}(M)$ is a consistent extension of ZFC, and $M$ is a prime model of $T.$

**P.S.** For the existence of pointwise definable models of ZFC, see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified), or consult the paper of J. D. Hamkins, D. Linetsky, and J. Reitz, [Pointwise definable models of set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/), *Journal of Symbolic Logic* 78(1), pp. 139-156, 2013.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Apparently things are not as clean cut as I had thought.