# Is there an isomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Is there an isomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as fields?

It seems that since they are both algebraically closed and characteristic 0, there is an isomorphism. However, I am not able to actually construct the isomorphism, nor is it clear that such an isomorphism must exist.

Is there an isomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ to $\mathbb{C}$ as fields?

Comment: See also [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23264/are-c-and-barq-p-isomorphic).

Comment: Thank you very much @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 6):

If you believe the axiom of choice, yes there is. They are algebraically
closed fields of the same characteristic, and the same uncountable cardinality. Therefore they both have the same transcendence degree over $\Bbb Q$. Zorn's lemma can be used to prove an isomorphism between them,
just not one that you can actually write down.

Comment: There isn't actually a theorem that you can't write one down. In fact,
 [it's possible that every set can be written down](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified).