# paradoxical decomposition: the banach-tarski paradox

Tags: real-analysis

is there a simple and vivid example of paradoxical decomposition specifically on the banach-tarski paradox? is there a math software that can be used as an application of the paradox?

Comment: I don't get what you mean... do you want to see the actual pieces in which you can decompose a ball and form two balls?

Answer (score 0):

The Banach-Tarski paradox consists of breaking a sphere into finitely many pieces and reassembling them into two disjoint using only rotations. The key point here is that the pieces are non-measurable. So there can never be an animation that depicts the decomposition and reassembly. (Thanks to user Hurkyl for the comment!)

Comment: Aside: [one *can* write down](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified) a putative paradoxical composition without invoking choice at all; the problem is proving that the decomposition doesn't leave any points out. IMO, the implausibility of an animation follows simply from the fact some pieces are non-measurable.

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found so, you might want to have a look at the Youtube video made by Vsauce of about 2 years ago [The Banach-Tarsi Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA). At 11:15 he starts talking explicitly about the breaking up of a sphere and reassembling it into two spheres and adds an animation of the process. It gives a nice visual illustration of the paradox and might help you to understand it a bit better what it is all about.