# What is the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes of infinite sequences in $\Bbb{Q}$ that converge in $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, set-theory

This started out as a question about Dedekind cuts and determining which of two interpretations of the definition of "Dedekind cut" is correct. While writing that question, I realized that I had unwittingly assumed that every real number is the limit of a convergent sequence of rationals.

This is a problem because 1) the set of such sequences may be countable depending on the definition of "convergence" and 2) "limits" define *equivalence classes* of such sequences, and the set of said equivalence classes may be countable even *if* the set of convergent sequences is not.

---

To lay down some ground rules, I know the set of *all* sequences of rational numbers ($\Bbb{Q}^\Bbb{N}$)to be uncountable, with cardinality equal to that of the power set of the integers ($2^{\aleph_0}$).$^{1}$

Now, the subset $S_Q$ of convergent sequences of rationals is a proper subset of $\Bbb{Q}^\Bbb{N}$ under all but one definition of "convergence" (that being "a sequence in $\Bbb{Q}$ converges iff it exists") so the possibility that the cardinality of the set of convergent sequences is strictly less than that of $\Bbb{Q}^\Bbb{N}$ - and potentially countable - is open.

If we restrict ourselves to either the set of definable or provably convergent sequences, then $S_Q$ is necessarily countable (proof sketch upon request). With that in mind, it seems reasonable that the set of convergent sequences of rationals must contain uncountably many undefinable members in order that the reals should remain uncountable.

**Edit:** I would add that "definable" here assumes a first-order theory in a countable language. I don't know anywhere near enough about pointclasses or hierarchies to discuss them in detail. For those interested, there are [pointwise-definable models of ZFC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4597.pdf) in which every sequence of rationals is definable.

That being said, this doesn't help me unless I can figure out a way to prove the existence of convergent but not provably convergent sequences of rationals (even then, I would *prefer* to have a "witness").

**Edit:** the existence of convergent but not provably convergent sequences is equivalent to the existence of Cauchy but not provably Cauchy sequences of rationals that converge in $\Bbb{R}$. The existence of such sequences is implied by the uncountability of the set of Cauchy sequences which converge to $x$ for every real number $x$ (though no such sequence can be [directly] defined). This can be proven in ZF by modifying the diagonal argument as long as $\forall p\in\Bbb{Q}.\forall 0<\varepsilon.\exists q\in\Bbb{Q}.0<|p-q|<\varepsilon$ (which ought to follow from any proof that the rationals, under their usual ordering, are a dense subset of the reals).

Setting this aside and assuming that the set of all convergent sequences of rationals *is* uncountable, and that each real number *is* the limit of at least one such sequence, I encounter another problem. The sequence of rationals defining a particular real number is not unique - that is, two or more distinct sequences may have the same limit and thus represent the same real number (the proof is trivial).

If $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S_Q$ where $\displaystyle\forall\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in S_Q.\mathbf{a}R\mathbf{b}\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ then presumably $\Bbb{R}\cong S_Q/R$. For each $x\in\Bbb{R}$ the set of sequences in $\Bbb{Q}$ converging to $x$ is - admitting the aforementioned unprovably convergent sequences - uncountable. Because $S_Q=\bigcup (S_Q/R)$, $S_Q$ remains uncountable even *if* $S_Q/R$ is countable (since the countable union of uncountable sets is uncountable).

I'm not sure how to go about proving that $S_Q/R$ is uncountable, especially given that assuming $S_Q/R$ *is* countable without first assuming that $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable fails to produce a contradiction.$^2$

---

**Next Step**

It at least seems plausible that $S_Q/R$ might be countable, but that my original premise (that every real is the limit of at least one *convergent* sequence of rationals) is false. If nothing else, we might consider that $S_Q/R$ represents something between the set of definable real numbers and the set of real numbers.

I would like to think that this is the case and that the number line can be filled in by adding *nonconvergent* sequences to $S_Q$. Intuitively, it would seem that the limit of a nonconvergent sequence cannot be a real number. However, since most real numbers are *undefinable*, and most such limits are *undefined*, it is in some ways more intuitive to think that equivalence classes of such nonconvergent sequences account for the remaining [undefinable] real numbers. Since the set of nonconvergent sequences has uncountably many uncountable subsets, the equivalence classes of nonconvergent sequences could account for the uncountability of the real numbers if $S_Q$ were countable.

While the construction of such equivalence classes is completely impossible in any sort of recursively definable sense, it might be possible to get a glimpse by assigning stages in the construction to a net over some uncountable space (think of something like an analogue Turing machine).

---

Footnotes:

$^1$I'm leaving continuum hypothesis and choice out of this question because that dead horse has been beaten enough and I'm not trying to start a war.

$^2$The easy way out would of course be to say that *because* $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, $S_Q/R$ must be uncountable. However, the purpose of this endeavor was to show that the real numbers, constructed using Dedekind cuts, are uncountable - at least, given a particular understanding of "Dedekind cut". Asserting that $S_Q/R$ is uncountable because the real numbers are and using this to show that the set of Dedekind cuts is uncountable ultimately amounts to saying "the reals are uncountable because the reals are uncountable" - which, while not strictly false, is not particularly insightful.

Comment: That ${\mathbb Q}^{\mathbb N}$ has size $2^{\aleph_0}$ is provable in ZF.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that the set of "definable" rational sequences is countable -- for example we might be in a model of set theory in which [every set is definable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified), and thus particular where every sequence of rationals is definable. The informal argument you have in mind will not work because the correspondence between "definitions" (as finite strings of symbols) and the sequences they define does not necessarily exist _as a set_ in the model.

Comment: It is difficult to speak about "convergent" sequences of rationals before you have defined the reals they might converge to. The usual way to sidestep that is to focus our attention on _Cauchy_ sequences (which is a property that can be defined using only the naturals and rationals), and then declare by fiat that every Cauchy sequence has a real that it converges to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If AC fails, then there may still be undefinable members. I want to avoid involving AC or nonstandard models of ZF. I would consider " $X$ definable" as there being some first-order formula $\phi$ in the Kleene closure of our alphabet s.t. $X=\{x\mid\phi(x)\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm While every Cauchy sequence converges to a real number, this does not guarantee that every real number is the limit of a Cauchy sequence. It may also be the case that no proof exists one way or the other for a particular sequence. The existence of such sequences is a consequence of the Kleene star of our alphabet (which contains all proofs) being countable.

Comment: @R.Burton: If you _define_ the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, then _by that very definition_ every real number does have at least one Cauchy sequence defining it. If you've defined real numbers as Dedekind cuts, then you need a small bit of work to find a matching sequence, but it's not hard -- for example, let the $n$th element of the sequence be the largest multiple of $1/n$ that is in the _left_ part of the cut.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That was the idea, but the set of such sequences appears to be countable (unless the set of Cauchy sequences itself contains [uncountably many] undefinable members?) That's why I wanted to prove the existence of convergent but not provably convergent sequences.

Comment: @R.Burton: There must be something wrong with whatever reasoning leads you to conclude that "the set of such sequences appears to be countable". I have trouble following your explanations fully, but it looks vaguely like you are conflating "can be proved to be Cauchy" with "is actually Cauchy". Properties can very well be _true_ of things without being _provable_ about them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98044/discussion-between-r-burton-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: The set of equivalence classes of infinite sequence that converge in $\mathbb R$  ***IS*** $\mathbb R$.

Comment: "While every Cauchy sequence converges to a real number, this does not guarantee that every real number is the limit of a Cauchy sequence."  Yes it does!  That's the *very* definition of the real numbers!

Comment: "That was the idea, but the set of such sequences appears to be countable"  if $q_i \to x$ is a cauchy sequenc and if arbitrarily replace one specific $q_k$ with a different value then resulting sequence will also be a cauchy sequence converging to $x$.  So by Cantor diagonalization the set of such sequences is uncountable.

Comment: @fleablood I'm not sure I follow, what are you diagonalizing?

Comment: @R.Burton To show that your claim re: countability is false.

Comment: If you have a countable list of cauchy sequences converging to $x$, simply replace the the $n$th term of the $n$ sequence with another value.  The result is a cauchy sequence converging to $x$ that was not on the list.  So there are an uncountably many cauchy sequence converging to $x$.

Comment: @fleablood Correction: For any countable list $L$ of Cauchy sequences converging to $x$, the set $D$ of all diagonals contains at least one Cauchy sequence not in $L$ which converges to $x$ (there are *also* non-Cauchy sequences in $D$).

Comment: You're right my diagonalization of just changing would have resulted in a sequence where *every* term is changed.  But we can change it to a rational with a distance of $\frac 1{2^n}$ of the n-th term of the $n$th sequence.  That will result in a cauchy sequence not in the list that converges to $x$>

Comment: 1)By definition of real numbers there is at least one cauchy sequence of rationals that converge to $x$. 2)if $\{q_i\}$ is such a sequence then for any natural $n> 1$ the sequence $\{q_i + \frac 1{n^i}\}$ is a cauchy sequence converging to $x$ so there are countably infinitely many cauchy sequences converge to $x$. 3)Let $\{S_i\}$  where $S_k = \{{q_k}_i\}$ be a countably infinite list of sequences converge to $x$.  Select the sequence $Q_i$ so that $Q_i \ne {q_i}_i$ but $|Q_i -{q_i}_i|< 2^{-i}$ then $Q_i$ is a sequence converging to $x$ that is not on the list. So there are uncountable many.

Comment: Oh... wait... Oh, it's fixable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me address your question about provability. It is in fact quite easy to exhibit a pair of sequences of rationals $C_1, C_2$ such that

- ZFC (indeed, much less) proves that exactly one is a Cauchy sequence, but
- ZFC doesn't prove that $C_1$ is Cauchy and ZFC doesn't prove that $C_2$ is Cauchy.

Semantically speaking, in every model of ZFC, one of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is Cauchy, but both possibilities can occur.

Specifically:

- Let the $i$th term of $C_1$ be $i$ if the continuum hypothesis holds, and $0$ if the continuum hypothesis fails.
- Let the $i$th term of $C_2$ be $i$ if the continuum hypothesis fails, and $0$ if the continuum hypothesis holds.

ZFC proves that $C_1$ is Cauchy iff CH fails, and ZFC proves that $C_2$ is Cauchy iff CH holds, but ZFC does *not* decide CH so ZFC cannot tell which of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is Cauchy.

---

Next, let's sketch a ZFC proof (indeed, vastly less than ZFC) that the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences - which I'll denote "$\mathbb{R}_C$" - is indeed uncountable. **This is just [Cantor's first argument superficially rephrased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article#Second_theorem)**, but you might find this rephrasing helpful.

Specifically, for a Cauchy sequence $C=(c_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and rationals $p<q$, say that $C$ *avoids* the interval $[p, q]$ if for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$\forall m>n(c_m\not\in [p,q])$$ (that is, if $C$ eventually leaves $[p,q]$ and never comes back). It's a good exercise to show that whenever $p<q, r<s$ are rationals with $[p,q]\cap [r,s]=\emptyset$ (that is, either $p<q<r<s$ or $r<s<p<q$) we either have $C$ avoids $[p,q]$ or $C$ avoids $[r,s]$ (or both).

Next, we'll define a pair of operations on closed intervals with rational endpoints: for $[a, b]$ a closed interval with rational endpoints, let $$Left([a,b])=[a, a+{b-a\over 3}]\quad\mbox{and}\quad Right([a,b])=[b-{b-a\over 3}, b].$$ (Think about the construction of the Cantor set.)

Now we're ready to diagonalize (if we assume Choice; if not, we neeed an extra step, which I've outlined below). Suppose $(\mathbb{E}_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. Pick (via Choice) a representative $C_i=(c_j^i)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ of each $\mathbb{E}_i$.

We now define a sequence of closed intervals $(I_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ as follows:

- $I_0=[0,1]$.
- $I_{n+1}=Left(I_n)$ if $C_n$ avoids $Left(I_n)$, and $Right(I_n)$ otherwise.

Now let $a_n$ be the left endpoint of $I_n$, and consider the sequence $A=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. It's easy to check that this is Cauchy and not equivalent to any $C_i$; thus, the equivalence class $\mathbb{A}$ of $A$ is not in $\mathbb{E}$, and this completes the proof.

---

If we didn't assume choice, the passage from $(\mathbb{E}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ to $(C_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ appears problematic at first. However, we do in fact have a canonical way to pick representatives of equivalence classes.

Namely, suppose $\mathbb{E}$ is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences. Fix an enumeration $(q_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, let $p_i$ be the rational with minimal index such that some (equivalently, every) element of $\mathbb{E}$ does *not* avoid $[p_i, p_i+{1\over i}]$, and let $C=(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. It's a good exercise to check that this is well-defined and is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{E}$.

---

Finally, a comment on definability and models.

What the above shows is that ZFC (indeed, much less) proves that the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals is uncountable. This means that whenever $M$ is a model of ZFC (externally countable or not), there is no bijection *in $M$* between *what $M$ thinks is* the set of Cauchy sequences and *what $M$ thinks is* $\mathbb{N}$. Of course, such a bijection might exist in reality (= externally).

Moreover, this does *not* contradict the possibility of every Cauchy sequence in $M$ being definable in $M$; this is a special case of the fact that pointwise definable models (which you mention) can exist. The map sending a Cauchy sequence in $M$ to a definition in $M$ of that Cauchy sequence is *not* definable in $M$ (per Tarski), and so we don't get a contradiction with the *internal* uncountability of the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.